# Mobile Connect CSV Unsubscribe Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Quick question, If I manually upload a list to mobile connect with a status of "Unsubscribe" then later in journey builder select "Subscribe all contacts to journey" will that user get the SMS message? I understand that if a user themselves manually opts-out they will not get a SMS but does the same rule apply to a CSV upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your manual import finishes and correctly adjusts the subscription status to "Not opted-in". If you are using the "Subscribe all contacts to a keyword" option, you are safe - the message won't be sent out of Journey Builder.